# which will perform better a JOIN or IN clause

Tags: sql, oracle11g, common-table-expression

Please suggest which of the following query will be faster for large data set. Actually i have to find non matching records between temp and COSTING_TABLE and the data set is in millions. We are yet to implement indexes but i am seeking for some efficient method to do the same.

```
SELECT tmp.PRINT, tmp.NAME, tmp.COST , tmp.CURRENCY, tmp.validity
                                    FROM TEMPTABLE tmp 
                                    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                                        FROM COSTING_TABLE  ct
                                                        WHERE (ct.print = tmp.print 
                                                        AND ct.name IN (SELECT name FROM CostMapping WHERE PRICE 'ABC')
                                                        AND ct.COST <> tmp.COST 
                                                        AND to_date(tmp.validity,'DD-MON-YY') > SYSDATE)
                                                      ) 
                                     AND tmp.name = 'ABC';
```

[image]

**WITH JOIN**

```
SELECT tmp.PRINT, tmp.NAME, tmp.COST , tmp.CURRENCY, tmp.validity 
FROM TEMPTABLE tmp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  
COSTING_TABLE ct
ON ct.print = tmp.print AND
 ct.name IN (SELECT name FROM CostMapping WHERE PRICE = 'ABC')
    AND ct.COST <> tmp.COST 
    AND to_date(tmp.valid_before,'DD-MON-YY') > SYSDATE
WHERE tmp.name = 'ABC' AND 
(ct.PRINT IS NULL OR ct.NAME IS NULL OR ct.COST IS NULL OR ct.validity IS NULL);
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: At first glance, the two queries do not look particularly similar to me -- different columns, different numbers of tables being referenced.

Answer (score 1):

If you are planning to create INDEXES on your column then using IN clause will be the same as using JOIN clause. But usually I prefer to use ANSI compliant JOINS.

You can also refer this [article](https://explainextended.com/2009/09/30/in-vs-join-vs-exists-oracle/):

> IN predicate is an ugly duckling of SQL. Due to the fact it appears
>   inefficient in the eye of an inexperienced developer, it is generally
>   considered non-efficient and EXISTS or a JOIN are advised to use
>   instead.
>
> However, Oracle optimizes IN fairly well, using indexes, UNIQUE
>   constraints, NOT NULL modifiers and other extra information wisely.